# pch in plot with R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset that I have plotted, I am now trying to build a legend with the corresponding point styles, the points are plotted correctly on the graph but the legend shows the same symbol for the binary response set. I am a bit confused as to why and hope it is something small.  Here is my code

```
# data should already be loaded in from the project on the school drive
library(survival)
attach(lace)
lace

# To control the type of symbol we use we will use psymbol, it takes
# value 1 and 2
psymbol <- FAILURE + 1 
table(psymbol)
plot(AGE, TOTAL.LACE, pch=(psymbol))
legend(0, 15, c("FAILURE = 1", "FAILURE = 0"), pch=(psymbol))]
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FaDj.jpg)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pysmbol` is a vector of length `n`, where `n` is the number of data points in your data set. Your `legend` call is passing this *entire* vector to `pch` where you really only need a vector of length 2. Hence `legend` uses the first two elements of `psymbol` for `pch`. Now, go look at `psymbol[1:2]`. I'll be very surprised if that doesn't return two `1`s.

I'd suggest you do `pch = unique(psymbol)`. It looks like it should be a numeric vector so that should work.

Note that you don't need parentheses around `psymbol` in your calls, and `attach()`ing an object is considered poor practice unless you quickly `detach()` immediately after. See `?with` for an alternative approach.

Comment: I had no clue about that, thank you for the answer, worked like a charm.

Comment: I ended up doing the following as well: `psymbol <- unique(FAILURE + 1)`

Comment: I don't think you want that; if you do this before the `plot()` call, it will result in `1:2` being repeated (`1,2,1,2,1,2,...`) to length `n`. Hence the symbols used to plot may not be the correct ones - given what you said earlier, it would at the very least plot the second observation in the wrong symbol.